# jQuery sets a temporary id on elements every time it traverses

Tags: jquery, performance

I noticed in Chrome element inspector that certain elements are being manipulated. upon inspecting further by breaking on attribute manipulation. I noticed that jQuery setting a temporary attribute ID then deleting it every time.  I traced it back to a code I made to check on visible elements.  The code I made is to check if user selected elements inside the visible option containers regularly.

Would this have impact on performance and if I set an ID manually to all those elements, would that help?

Comment: what do you mean by performance?

Comment: I mean speed-wise. would this slow down the page?

Comment: it shouldn't slow it down